# TCL - uniq content of file

Tags: tcl

I am trying to uniquify the file content. The game and score is repeated sometimes, I am trying to write out to file1

Input:

```
game score
a 1
a 1
a 2
b 1
b 2
b 2
```

Output:

```
Uniq1 a 1
Uniq2 a 2
Uniq3 b 1
Uniq4 b 2
```

Code:

```
   while {[gets $inputfile] > 0} {

        set g1 [lindex $token end]
        set g2 [lindex $token end-1]

      incr gcount
         puts $file1 "Uniq$gcount =$g1 $g2"

      }
```

Comment: Are you trying to do unique lines across the whole file, or just to coalesce runs of identical lines?

Answer (score 3):

Just store the lines as keys in a `dict` and iterate over the keys after reading all the input to print the values (In the order they appear in the input) without including duplicates. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc main {} {
    # Discard header line
    gets stdin
    while {[gets stdin line] > 0} {
        dict set lines $line 1
    }
    set i 1
    dict for {line _} $lines {
        puts "Uniq$i $line"
        incr i
    }
}
main
```

Running this produces:

```
Uniq1 a 1
Uniq2 a 2
Uniq3 b 1
Uniq4 b 2
```

Comment: I have existing code that uses lindex to get the column 1 and column too? So, how can I use the above suggestion with LINDEX?

Comment: Maybe dict does not work for me? I test out the suggested code and does not produce what you have?

Comment: @jay I literally copied and pasted your sample input into a file and fed that to the tcl code I posted (`tclsh demo.tcl < input.txt`). What happens for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, it just doesnt give any output.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few options, depending on the complexity. If the duplicates for example always occur one after the other, then I would just save the current row as previous row and when I get to the next row, I compare it to the previous row:

```
set previous(g1) ""
set previous(g2) ""

while {[gets $inputfile] > 0} {

    set g1 [lindex $token end]
    set g2 [lindex $token end-1]

    if {$previous(g1) != $g1 && $previous(g2) != $g2} {
        incr gcount
        puts $file1 "Uniq$gcount $g1 $g2"
        set previous(g1) $g1
        set previous(g2) $g2
    }

}
```

If the duplicate could happen anywhere, then I'd do it like this:

```
array set previous {}

while {[gets $inputfile] > 0} {

    set g1 [lindex $token end]
    set g2 [lindex $token end-1]

    if {![info exists previous($g1,$g2)]} {
        incr gcount
        puts $file1 "Uniq$gcount $g1 $g2"
        set previous($g1,$g2) ""
    }

}
```